# CSS not referring after hosting in iis

Tags: css, asp.net, iis

I m using vs2010 and iis 7

i hosted my web app in iis 7

like http://localhost/TestUI/login.aspx

But the css file not referring..!

I opened the developer options and tried to see the css file

like http://localhost/TestUI/css/style1.css

It throwing error like

> 401.3 - unathorized - You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL)
>   configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web
>   server.

I have tried many ways to solve it..

Gave access to IUSR to wwwroot folder in properties -> security

Changed Anonymous Authentication to Application pool identity

Used (~) in the css url in aspx page

But don't know how to solve it ! what to do !!

Comment: Make sure you're searching from the right location. I was searching for IUSR on my work domain and finding nothing. Then I changed the location to my machine name.Note: It required both `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS`  having access for it to work on my machine.

Comment: Yes. IUSR and IIS_IUSRS  having full access, but still the same error throwing.

Comment: Make sure that application pool of your website and website both are running under the same identity. Then make sure that this identity has required permissions on the virtual directory

Comment: How to Make sure that application pool of your website and website both are running under the same identity ?

Comment: I don't i can explain it clearly or not let me try!! ...When you click on the `inetmgr` the default website will be seen on the right side you will find `view application pools` on clicking this , your web site will be under one of the items present so make sure they boooth under same application pool identity

Comment: try to give permission for the CSS folder, if u already did please verify once and second thing is In developer Tools under network tab try to see what error you getting for this css reference ..

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247603)

> This problem occurs when permissions for the file that the user is trying to access are denied to that user. This error message differs from a standard 401 error message, in that, the user has been logged on to the server, but the resource that the user is trying to access is restricted. For example, if only Administrators and LocalSystem have access to a file on the server and a user, who is a member of the Users group, tries to access it, the user receives a 401.3 (provided they can log on to the server).

The resolution states to check the NTFS permission on that file. Make sure users can access the same.

I found a [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/38222/iis-7-5-windows-7-http-error-401-3-unauthorized) that could help you with the solving the same. As per the thread,

> IIS 7 also creates "IUSR" as default user to access files via IIS. So make user IUSR has read access to files/folders.
>
> How to check if IUSR has read Access? Right Click -> Folder -> Properties -> Security Tab See if IUSR is in Group or user names list, If No.
>
> Click Edit -> Add -> Advanced -> Find Now -> Select IUSR and click OK four times